Why won't Google Earth Style Template show bucket options?
I am trying to set up a style template for a shapefile I am importing into google earth.
I have a table with a field where the values are either 1 or 3. I want different icons for the features based on that value.
However, when I specify the field I need to use, the bucket options do not appear for this field. It will show for other fields, but not this one. What am I doing wrong?
I've selected other fields and they work fine. When I select the field it should show a list of distinct values for the buckets, and with that list I should be able to select the icon for each bucket. But the list never appears.
